# How to add tabs at the bottom of ImageView in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabbed-activity

I want something like this, start with toolbar then an image and at the bottom of image tabs available(2-section).

Comment: Use Collapsing toolbar + viewpager + tab layout

Comment: thanks for the help.. buddy :)